# useradd ignores defaults in /etc/default/useradd

Tags: home-directory, default, useradd

FTP Migration.  Moving the FTP server from Windows to Ubuntu, and rebuilding the storage for FTP on a different server.  I'm doing a one time pass to create about 100 users, all with the same password, with home directories on the mounted remote server.  Here's what I'm running:

```
ls /media/OldFTP |
grep -Ev '^[[:digit:]]{4}|^P[[:digit:]]{4}|^W[[:digit:]]{4}' |
xargs -n1 -d'\n' useradd -m -g ftpusers -N -p [encryptedPassword]
```

This runs fine.  It does everything it's supposed to, except the home directory is in the standard location of /home/, instead of the location I defined in the /etc/default/useradd file and with `useradd -D -b /media/ftpShare`.  When I run `useradd -D` I get the setting I added with the previous command.

Why does useradd ignore these purported defaults?

Comment: Possibly this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1321854/comments/7

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since I stumbled upon the same problem and solved it, I share:
Apparently the defaults are no longer those in /etc/default/useradd but in  /etc/adduser.conf. I edited the latter and new users adhere to my defaults. It's in the manpage for adduser ... where I should have looked first.

Comment: `useradd` and `adduser` are different commands and use different locations  for configuration files.